# How to add more data to a table that already has primary key?

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table

I am new to Mysql so go easy. Forgive the lack of knowledge in this area.
But I have searched everywhere and it's stupid I can't just find this simple answer. Trying to make a fun app to promote pages, earn points, PPC type ads for fbook blah blah...

I currently have one {table1} with user data. 
UID, 
fname, 
lname, 
date added

And table2 for submitting user links for the ads to return on a page, 
it only has 
primary from the UID 
and 1 col right now able to add links to. 
With the primary key I want either username or uid but must be able to add more to the existing primary key so I can call the user and all links. I can add like this but of course have to delete myself to add more to the table...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO {$table} VALUES ('{$userid}', '{$user_link}')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error updating database');
```

Then, say they add another one later

```
if new submission check existing then 
add new column to existing uid... link#2=http://
```

What am I missing. It's hard to even word the question that's why I am putting this here for search results! HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table can't have a database primary key on UID.  By definition UID as a primary key MUST be unique.  So either you need.

- a COMBINED KEY UID & USER_LINK (ORACLE thinking)
- No Key at all  (It works; but then you can have duplicates )
- A generic AutoNum key which adds 1 for each record (MSFT thinking)

When you say something is a Primary Key, you mean the value will NEVER be null and it will ALWAYS be UNIQUE in the table.  You have to be careful with this; somethings you think are unique, in fact are not.

In this case the UNIQUE key is defined with user links  the same user has no need to have the same link (right?) so you could make a combined key between the two.

Comment: Awesome finally someone can lay these things out on the table for me. I'll do some Googling and see what I come up with. I'll keep it posted...Thanks again!

Comment: Combined was easiest for those who need this. Went to PHPmyAdmin checked both my users id and link columns, clicked     unique index     so they can't have same links on same account...Perfect now!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `PRIMARY KEY` on table2, which is, by definition, unique.  Use a regular index as a `FOREIGN KEY` back to table11.

Comment: Wait, is the user only allowed to have one entry in table2?  If so, you'll want to use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`.  Sorry that I missed that before.

Comment: If you mean 'no duplicate links', then you'd want a unique index on (uid, link) on table2.  There's no primary key in that table.

Comment: Ok I think I got it...Here is what I did

Open PHPMyAdmin;

    1.) Click primary for table1 on uid
    2.) Go to table2 click index uid
    3.) Choose both uid+link on table2 click unique


Now it seems to work perfect is this optimized?

Comment: If it created two indexes on table2, that's overkill.  It can use the composite (uid, link) when just looking by uid.  Sounds like you're all set!

Comment: Your right 2 indexes made, updated to remove index re-added unique composite. Thanks your wonderful!